# Implement unpack b from Perl in PHP

Tags: php, pack, unpack

Given a string of bytes I want their binary representation such that the bits of each byte are ordered from least to most significant (as produced by Perl's `unpack "b*"`).

For example,

```php
"\x28\x9b"
```

should return

```php
"0001010011011001"
```

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15280213/20251268) Ilmari Karonen described how to achieve `pack "b*"` in PHP. So I thought all I have to do is split the hex string into bytes and run them through base_convert.

```php
function unpack_B($data) {
    $unpacked = unpack("H*", $data)[1];
    $nibbles = str_split($unpacked, 2);
    foreach ($nibbles as $i => $nibble) {
        $nibbles[$i] = base_convert($nibble, 16, 2);
    }
    return implode("", $nibbles);
}
```

However, It's returning something different.

What am I missing here?

Comment: *" In this post Ilmari Karonen described how to achieve pack b* in php"* - The post is about packing `B` not `b` - which is slightly different. And in no way should the binary string have the same length as the hext string, so something is wrong in your expectations.

Comment: A hex string represented in literal binary will always be 4x longer than the input. Also, neither of those binary representations are accurate for the given input, even partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the docs for perl's `pack()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack) it seems like `B` is the usual "big endian" [I know I'm abusing this term] "descending" bit order, and `b` is "little endian"/"ascending".

I honestly cannot parse what on earth that the code/answer you've linked is supposed to do, so I've written it all from scratch based on what the perl docs *say* the pack arguments do.

```php
function bin_to_litbin($input, $be=true) {
    return implode(
        '',
        array_map(
            function($a)use($be){
                $ret = str_pad(decbin(ord($a)), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                if(!$be) {
                    $ret = strrev($ret);
                }
                return $ret;
            },
            str_split($input, 1)
        )
    );
}

function litbin_to_bin($input, $be=true) {
    return implode(
        '',
        array_map(
            function($a)use($be){
                if(!$be) {
                    $a=strrev($a);
                }
                return chr(bindec($a));
            },
            str_split($input, 8)
        )
    );
}

$hex = '00289b150065b302a06c560094cd0a80';
$bin = hex2bin($hex);

var_dump(
    $hex,
    $cur =  bin_to_litbin($bin, false),
    bin2hex(litbin_to_bin($cur, false))
);
```

where `$be=true` is `B`/"big endian" and `$be=false` is `b`/"little endian".

Output:

```
string(32) "00289b150065b302a06c560094cd0a80"
string(128) "00000000000101001101100110101000000000001010011011001101010000000000010100110110011010100000000000101001101100110101000000000001"
string(32) "00289b150065b302a06c560094cd0a80"
```

Though truth be told I cannot think of *any* practical reason to ever encode data as literal zero and one characters. It is *wildly* unnecessary and wasteful compared to literally any other encoding. I would wager that that is why `B` and `b` were never implemented in PHP.

Base64 is 1.33x the length its input, hex is 2x, and literal binary is 8x.

Comment: I am sorry for my confusing text, I should have tried harder to explain my problem especially with a accurate example, I had truncated the output which led to more confusion, my apologies for that. Somehow you managed to understand exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much, this works perfectly. I am porting a function from a perl script to php and the pack/unpack b template was a hurdle for me.